# quadratic programming problem with positive constraints

Tags: optimization, quadratic-programming

Is there a non-iterative solution to the following quadratic programming problem with constrains? Is there any problem to think the variable as some square of another variable to get ride of the constrains?

$\min\quad x^TAx + b^Tx\qquad s.t. \quad x\geq 0 $

Regards,

Bo

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid that only in exceptional cases there is a non-iterative solution,
for instance of $A$ is diagonal, or if $-A^{-1}b\ge0$.